# Google Tag Manager and using triggers or tag sequencing

Tags: javascript, google-tag-manager

I have a custom HTML tag in my GTM, I want this to fire after another tag.

From my understanding, I would use the sequencing in my second tag to fire the Custom HTML tag.  However, would I ALSO set up the same trigger for both?

Mainly my Custom HTML tag is set to trigger on a 'ButtonA' click.  BUT my second tag is ALSO triggered on my 'ButtonA' click.

If I am using sequencing. Do I need the Custom HTML tag to have the button click too if the second tag is going to use the click of 'ButtonA' as well? Or should I keep the 'ButtonA' trigger on both of the tags.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can assign separate triggers to these tags, but in your certain scenario, where the trigger is the same, but the execution order is important, you should not assign the same trigger to the second tag. (Although default once-per-trigger setting will prevent it to run for multiple times for the trigger and the sequencing, this way you can ensure the order of execution.)

If you look at the second tag's settings summary, you can see, that although it will not have it's own triggers, it will follow TAG 1 immediately:

[image]